# "no runnable methods" on junit with custom annotation and all tests filtered

Tags: java, junit, annotations, test-runner

I'm using JUnit 4.11, extended the BlockJUnit4ClassRunner and used a custom annotation.
If the annotation is present with a certain parameter, the test will not be run.

This works fine, except for the case, that all tests in a class are filtered out but the custom test runner.

Basically exactly as described in this post: [JUnit4 skip test(s) according to custom java annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590557/junit4-skip-tests-according-to-custom-java-annotations)

I tried the workarounds mentioned in this post: [JUnit: how to avoid "no runnable methods" in test utils classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672466/junit-how-to-avoid-no-runnable-methods-in-test-utils-classes)

If the I introduce a dummy test, so that there is at least one test, that will always run, everything is fine. If all tests are not run, as they all have the annotation, I will get the "No runnable methods" exception.

I can live with the workaround, but there should be a better way. 
I'm thankful for any pointers or explanations what I did wrong or how to improve this situation.

Comment: I haven't tried them, but might it work if you implemented this with JUnit rules? http://cwd.dhemery.com/2010/12/junit-rules/

Comment: @Zutty, i will have a look, thanks. I've also seen, that junit-ext(ensions) would have a appropriate behavior, unfortunatelly, they are a bit dated and not in the maven (and therefor not an option for the project).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get this error due to the validation performed in `validateInstanceMethods` since computeTestMethods() returns an empty List:

```
protected void validateInstanceMethods(List<Throwable> errors) {
        validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(After.class, false, errors);
        validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(Before.class, false, errors);
        validateTestMethods(errors);

        if (computeTestMethods().size() == 0)
            errors.add(new Exception("No runnable methods"));
    }
```

You can override this method and remove the size validation or add your own validation which will take into consideration the annotated test methods.
Notice that this method is `@Deprecated` and will be removed in future versions.